# swift app crashes if user tries to refresh collection view when app is launching

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

i am implementing these two methods within a collection view controller that is my root view controller.

```
let currentMediaIndex = 0

override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if media.count == 0 {return}
    currentMediaIndex = getIndicesOfCellInView().row
    setIsBlockedListener(index: currentMediaIndex)
    if currentMediaIndex >= media.count - 2 && !collectionEmpty {
        addMedia()
    }
}

func getIndicesOfCellInView() -> IndexPath {
    var visibleRect = CGRect()
    visibleRect.origin = collectionView.contentOffset
    visibleRect.size = collectionView.bounds.size
    let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)
    if let indicesCellInView = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint) {
        return indicesCellInView
    }
    return IndexPath()
}
```

When I launch the application and scroll down to simulate a refresh, before any media which populates the collection view has loaded, the app crashes on line

```
currentMediaIndex = getIndicesOfCellInView().row
```

in the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` method. I'm trying to figure out why this is happening. The data which populates the collection view is retrieved in the `addMedia` method. `addMedia` is called in `viewDidLoad` but then also in the scroll method to get new data when necessary. So the safety `if media.count == 0 {return}` should account for the case when the user scrolling when there is no media i.e when the app is launching. However when the app is launching and i start scrolling like an impatient mad man... The app crashes.

Anybody have any ideas why?

Comment: The `addMedia` method can be quite slow. It is a call to firebase and takes a second or two to actually retrieve the collectionview data

Comment: By the way, you can use `collectionView.visibleCells` in conjunction with `collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)` to figure out, which index paths are currently active.

Comment: If the last line of `getIndicesOfCellInView` executes, you will be returning an empty index path, so accessing `.row` will fail.

Comment: Do you have a crash log?

Comment: Have you handled the  UI refresh on your main thread ?

Comment: @Palle the issue was returning an empty index path. Thank you!